# Как заполнить двумерный массив в Java

Tags: java

Не могу понять, как заполнить двумерный массив цифрами от 1 до 8 размерностью 8 на 8, кроме как заполнить его вручную. Но это очень не эффективно. Как сделать?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arr = new int[8][8];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = j + 1;
        }
    }
    for (int[] anArr : arr) {
        for (int anAnArr : anArr) {
            System.out.print(anAnArr + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```